# Entrypoint doesn't contain a main function on the flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

How can fix the error and run the my code
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see in your files tree the `main.dart` file, I assume that you deleted it, Dart/Flutter project running starts from there, exactly from it's `main()` method.

You just need to undo the deletion of that file, or creating a new one under the `/lib` directory